# Because of Schema.org/Person markup, Google+ uses the name of the person as the page title when sharing

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-plus

I am not concerned about the fact that Google+ will use the person's name instead of the page title. However, the person's name is not the main keyword the webpage is optimized for.

The page is optimized for $name photos and $name movies. Will the use of schema.org/Person markup (which is implemented correctly and does not give any errors) influence rankings for the other keywords in any way?

Answer (score 2):

When sharing on Google Plus, Google will only use Schema if no [The Open Graph protocol (OGP)](http://ogp.me/) is detected. In the event that no Schema or OGP is found then Google Plus will revert to the normal meta data that is used for ranking on Google Search. Obviously if none of these are found then Google will scrap text what it thinks is more ideal.

OGP is the standard format for setting page information which is then reflected when sharing on Social Media Platforms.

*OGP looks something like this:*

```
<meta property="og:title" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:description" content="..."/>
```

*Here's some additional  information about OGP that I answered awhile ago on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29067915/1892635):*

> [The Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) is supported by a wide range of social
>   platforms which includes:
>
> 1. [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph)
> 2. [Pinterest Developers](https://developers.pinterest.com/rich_pins_article/)
> 3. [Linkedin](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)
> 4. [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started)
> 5. [Google Plus](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)
>
> Twitter however is singled out because they have decided to use their
>   own called [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started).
>
> *Twitter Cards look like this:*
>
> ```
> <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
> <meta name="twitter:site" content="@example" />
> <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@example" />
> <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com" />
> <meta property="og:title" content="Just an Example Title" />
> <meta property="og:description" content="Example: Head, Shoulders, Knees and Toes! />
> <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/knees-toes.jpg" />
> ```

Summary

If you want better control of what information appears when sharing articles on social media platforms then you should interment OGP and Twitter Cards to your website.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not using Schema as ranking factor at this time, [but may be they will use in future - said by john mulller](http://searchengineland.com/google-may-add-structured-markup-data-to-ranking-algorithm-230402).

Schema is generally used for markup, so search engine understand/recognize your content more deeply. Yes, it may influence in ranking for particular query, checkout john example from above link.

Comment: Can indirectly improve SEO however through an increase click-rate on rich data appearing in search results which obviously gives more opportunity for natural SEO to occur.

Comment: Simon@You're right schema that is used for rich snippet may affect in CTR, but not all type of schema tags used in rich snippet  :)